# Forwarding RDP via a Linux machine using iptables: Not working

Tags: linux, windows, iptables, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I have a Linux machine and a Windows machine behind a router that implements NAT (the diagram might be overkill, but was [fun to make](http://www.gliffy.com/gliffy/)):

[image: network setup]

I am forwarding RDP port (3389) on the router to the Linux machine because I want to audit RDP connections. For the Linux machine to forward RDP traffic, I wrote these iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination win-box
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

The port is listening on the Windows machine:

```
C:\Users\nimmy>netstat -a

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  (..snip..)
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           WIN-BOX:0         LISTENING
  (..snip..)
```

And the port is forwarding on the Linux machine:

```
# tcpdump port 3389
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
01:33:11.451663 IP shieldsup.grc.com.56387 > linux-box.myapt.lan.ms-wbt-server: Flags [S], seq 94663035, win 8192, options [mss 1460], length 0
01:33:11.451846 IP shieldsup.grc.com.56387 > win-box.myapt.lan.ms-wbt-server: Flags [S], seq 94663035, win 8192, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

However, I am not getting any successful RDP connections from the outside. The port is not even responding:

```
C:\Users\outside-nimmy>telnet example.com 3389
Connecting To example.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3389: Connect failed
```

Any ideas?

### Update

Per @Zhiqiang Ma, I looked at `nf_conntrack` proc file during a connection attempt and this is what I see (192.168.3.1 = linux-box, 192.168.3.5 = win-box):

```
# cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack | grep 3389
ipv4     2 tcp      6 118 SYN_SENT src=4.79.142.206 dst=192.168.3.1 sport=43142 dport=3389 packets=6 bytes=264 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.3.5 dst=4.79.142.206 sport=3389 dport=43142 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 secmark=0 zone=0 use=2
```

### 2nd update

Got `tcpdump` on the router and it seems that win-box is sending an RST packet:

```
21:20:24.767792 IP shieldsup.grc.com.45349 > linux-box.myapt.lan.3389: S 19088743:19088743(0) win 8192 <mss 1460>
21:20:24.768038 IP shieldsup.grc.com.45349 > win-box.myapt.lan.3389: S 19088743:19088743(0) win 8192 <mss 1460>
21:20:24.770674 IP win-box.myapt.lan.3389 > shieldsup.grc.com.45349: R 721745706:721745706(0) ack 755785049 win 0
```

Why would Windows be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add port in iptables rules?:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination win-box:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

I am not very sure it's the reason. But I usually do it in this way: http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/

You can all try flush the tables first: iptables -t nat -F; iptables -F
and then add these two rules in case other rules in your iptables block the connection.

You may also

```
cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

and see the content there. Each forwarding connection has entries there.

*Note*: MASQUERADE is required as well if the outbound route from windows does not by default pass through the `iptables` box; see comments below ( you may need to unhide).

Comment: Hi there! 8 out of 10 posts refer to your own blog. Though you do quote some information too: is referring to that blog really needed?

Comment: @Zhigiang Ma: I added an update.

Comment: @Arjan Hi! Thanks for pointing it out. I will take care. Actually, I refer to my own blog which solves similar problem before and then I answer these questions. The answer is short usually and to the point and the blog provides more details. But I will take care of this and only add the link when it is very helpful to the answer.

Comment: @Nimmy Lebby I think Router is the gateway of both linux-box and win-box. Am I right? Then do you mind make the linux-box the gateway of the win-box? That may solve the problem. The incoming packet goes in this way: Internet -> Router -> linux-box -> win-box. But the outgoing packet goes in different way: win-box -> Router -> Internet. linux-box is confused and mark the incoming packet as "[UNREPLIED]". I use port-forwarding on the gateway, which works quite well and I believe the two rules by now should work if linux-box is win-box's gateway.

Comment: @Nimmy Lebby: If you just want audit the RDP connections on linux-box, I think you may log and drop the packet received by linux-box. And leave the Router to forward RDP connections to win-box.

Comment: I enabled Masquerading `/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING MASQUERADE` and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: you missed `-j`. The command is  `/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 2):

I saw you solved the issue with MASQUERADE. I didn't notice that last comment was hidden, so I had to solve the question for my own, thanks to the great Iptables Tutorial (look for it in Freshmeat). I did almost the same as you, but doing a SNAT instead of MASQUERADE, since the linux box has a static local IP. MASQUERADE would be more appropriate if the linux box had its IP given by DHCP, otherwise it's told to be a more processor consuming task.

I didn't need any FORWARD rule, although I had to

echo 1 | sudo tee  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: Yeah, this seems like the correct answer to me.  SNAT sould work well for connections that come from a known IP range, MASQUERADE worked well for my case ( the outbound proxy was _not_ the default route back on the windows side)

Answer (score 0):

This was my method on CentOS 7:

First, enable IPv4 forwarding - in /etc/sysctl.conf ensure there is the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then configure iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination <WINDOWS SERVER IP>

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally, ensure iptables applies these rules on boot - many guides on the internet.